# I can understand "global var" in Tcl, but what does "global $var" mean?

Tags: tcl

I'm a learner in Tcl language, I can't understand the use of *global* in this proc:

```
proc linkPeers { link } {
    global $link
    set entry [lsearch -inline [set $link] "nodes {*}"]
    return [lindex $entry 1]
}
```

*"global var"* refers to an external, global variable named `var`.

*"global $var"* I can't understand, who can tell me?

Comment: This is a complex concept in Tcl. It passes an argument that is a string containing the name of a global variable.

Comment: I would not call it necessarily "complex". There is more complex stuff in Tcl :) However, one needs to appreciate the variable names, channel names etc. are just arguments to a command and only receive their additional interpretation because of that.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a bit strange, and is actually buggy.

It should have been this instead (`#0` in quotes for syntax highlighting reasons only):

```
proc linkPeers { link } {
    upvar "#0" $link items
    set entry [lsearch -inline $items "nodes {*}"]
    return [lindex $entry 1]
}
```

The key is that the `link` argument is the name of a global variable, yet you want to access it as a local variable within the procedure. The `global` command does that, but the name is a variable so you have to use `[set $link]` to do the read afterwards. Switching to using `upvar #0` instead of `global` lets us use a *different, fixed name* locally, and that makes it easier to use elsewhere.

The bug in the original code? The global variable had better not be called either `link` or `entry`!

Comment: Remember, variables in Tcl procedures are always local unless you explicitly say otherwise. There are several commands for doing that: `global`, `upvar`, `variable` and `namespace upvar`. (TclOO _methods_ can also have variables with instance lifetime and class scope.)